# Apache Zookeeper Issue with Changing default Port

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying install Zookeeper and Kafka for a basic test 
And have to change the Client port in Zookeeper to a port available/open like below,

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=56xxx
```

However even after changing it in zookeeper property file while I start the Kafka server it tries to connect to default 2181 port, like below and Kafka  server is not starting.

```
Opening socket connection to server 
localhost/127.0.0.1:2181.
......
INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: 
Connection refused 
-------------
```

I am stuck with this issue, Apart from Zookeeper properties file is there any other config or properties file I have to change, so that Kafka looks for the new Zookeeper client port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit `zookeeper.connect` in the Kafka's `server.properties` file